# Realm migration memory leak iOS

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, realm, realm-migration

I am getting memory leak during migration using Realm (v1.0.2). 
My code looks like that:

```
        let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                migration.enumerate(MyClassRealm.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) in

                    newObject!["remoteId"] = 0
                    newObject!["deleted"] = false
                    newObject!["dirty"] = true
                    newObject!["updated"] = 0
                })
            }
    })

    // Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    // Now that we've told Realm how to handle the schema change, opening the file
    // will automatically perform the migration
    do {
        let _ = try Realm()
    } catch {
        TSLog.error(error as NSError)
    }
```

Stack trace:
[image]

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without symbols for the intermediate frames of the stack trace, but I suspect you're running into [Realm Cocoa issue #2933](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2933), which appears to be a memory leak due to a bug in Swift's runtime libraries.